# Is there an easier way to do a calculation using every nth row of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, with name of the state and daily price of a product in december (note: the weekend/holiday data is not available in the data). It looks something like this:

[image: Input Data]

---

For each state I would like to calculate the 3 day change in price of the product. I tried something like this to calculate the price change:

```
days=3

for k in df["name"].unique():
      test_df=df[df["name"]==k]
      test_df=test_df.reset_index(drop=True)
      test_df["3_chg"]=np.nan


    for i in range(0,test_df.shape[0]-days):
        test_df["3_chg"].iloc[i]=(test_df.iloc[i]["product_price"]/test_df.iloc[i+days]["product_price"])-1
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Output]

I am getting the desired output using my code. However, I would like to know if there is more effiecient way to the same calculation. My code works fast for a small sample of data, however if I am using the data for all 50 states it takes a lot of time.

Please let me know, if there's an alternative. Thanks

Comment: (df['product_price']-df.groupby('name')['product_price'].shift(3))/df['product_price']

Comment: Thanks it worked. I used :    df["3_chg"]=(df['product_price']/df.groupby('name')['product_price'].shift(-3))-1

Comment: Would you like me convert it to an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `shift`

```
df['3_change']=(df['product_price']-df.groupby('name')['product_price'].shift(3))/df['product_price']
```